# How can I use query string (--data-urlencode) in an NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, http, curl, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to translate the following `GET` request to an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: sdasfasdf" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: asdfasdfasdfasd" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"arrayKey":2}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/RandomObject
```

I know how to set the headers and the method, but not how to add the `--data-urlencode` part.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may encode the string using the `-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` method. Then, you just need to append the string to the URL.

```
NSString *URLPrefix = @"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/RandomObject";
NSString *encodedQuery = [@"where={\"arrayKey\":2}" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", URLPrefix, encodedQuery]];
[request setURL:URL];
```